# Eclipse remote debug to a glassfish server running on a VM on the same host

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I want to debug my project in eclipse. I have a glassfish server in a virutal machine(running solaris) on the same machine. What ports should i specify so it can recognize the server.

Answer (score 1):

Start the server in debug mode 
asadmin start-domain --debug
This will start the glassfish in debug mode and port is 9009. In the remote debugger configuration of eclipse mention the IPaddress of vm and the port number.